# this.pickupStatus.emit is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a provider that listens to changes to my firestore database and changes the status of a driver pickup request status. 
here is my pickuprequest function in my driver's provider

```
 getDriverPickupRequest(id)
{
this.DriverCollection.doc<Driver>(id).valueChanges()
                .subscribe(data => {
                        this.pickuprequest.changePickupStatus(data.pickupRequest);

}
```

Now i have a service that watches the change and emits it to my home page.

```
private pickupRequest = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public pickupStatus = this.pickupRequest.asObservable();

changePickupStatus(value: boolean) {
this.pickupStatus.emit(value);
}

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
//console.log('Hello PickuprequestProvider Provider');

}
```

Now i get an error that says 'this.pickupStatus.emit is not a function'. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: @PankajParkar .next also gives the same error

Comment: Replace `this.pickupStatus.emit(value);` by `this. pickupRequest.next(value);`

Comment: @PatrickObafemi my bad. check my answer with detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BehaviorSubject` has a `next` method on it that is used to push new values to the observable.

**Problem:** You're calling `emit` on `pickupStatus` which is an `Observable` when you should have called `next` on `pickupRequest` which is a `BehaviorSubject`

**Fix:**

```
private pickupRequest = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public pickupStatus = this.pickupRequest.asObservable();

changePickupStatus(value: boolean) {
  this.pickupRequest.next(value);
}
```

Use `this.pickupRequest.next(value);` where we are essentially pushing a new value on the `pickupRequest` which is a `BehaviorSubject` by using the `next` method on it.

Answer (score 1):

`.emit()` only works on `EventEmitter`, using `.next()` on pickup status won't work as `Observable` is read-only.

Comment: .next() only works on Subject or any class that extends Subject. Convert pickupStatus to eventEmitter and use emit() and it will work.

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor .next will work for both Subject and Behavior subject. Every observable in RxJs .next is the default method to emit the value

Comment: @NinjaJami as per http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html observable is read only. Subject is the one that can emit values via next().

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-subject-and-behaviorsubject-g6qhwt?file=app%2Fmyservice.ts

Comment: @AndreiDumitrescu-Tudor offical documentation http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject

Comment: Pickupstatus is a BehaviourSubject as a Observable from asObservable(). This makes it read only.

Answer (score 1):

`emit` method exist on `EventEmitter` object not on `BehaviourSubject`. Over here you are exposing the stream using `this.pickupRequest.asObservable()` method. I believe this is safest way to expose a stream so that the consumer of this stream will not push any data into a stream. **Basically to prevent leaky abstraction**. If consumer tries to do `pickupStatus.next(data)` on that it will result to an error. This is expected behavior. This way we give `readonly` access to consumer of a stream.

In order to send data over a stream you have to call `.next` method on `BehaviorSubject` instance, it auto magically let subscribers knows that new data has pushed into a stream.

```
pickupRequest.next(data)
```